# 2sxc Content-Type Import Fails with Languages Error

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc App that was written about 3 years ago and was last modified using 2sxc 9.43.2 LTS on DNN v8+. I restored the old DNN site and got everything working locally. I wanted to import this app in to a modern DNN v9.10+. I chose 2sxc v13.12.1 LTS. I installed that on the new, clean install of DNN 9.10.02 and then upgraded 2sxc on the old DNN v8 site to v13.12.1. Tested the app, still working! I figured if 2sxc was the same on both instances I'd have a pretty good chance of the import/export working.

First I tried exporting the whole app. That fails and I can't find any useful errors logged anywhere. So I switched and decided I would just export the content-types and rebuild the app manually since it only had 3 or 4 views, 3 content-types, and 1 query.

But exporting any of the content-types fails on import. See screen-clip below. I think I understand the error, but I am not clear as to what I need to do to fix this. Both the old site and the new site only have the DNN default, US English. Neither ever had another language added, there doesn't appear to be any differences in the DNN settings for this, I compared them side by side.

So what is the fix? Is there something I can change in 2sxc or the App in the old or new site to get the export/import to align? Can I just add the needed language to the Zone? If yes, where and how do I do that?

Can you explain what the error means, "entity has 1 zone has 0 used-list: 'en-us'"?

If I just need to add 'en-us' in the Zone, what does that mean or how do I do it?

screen clip:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the json which is to be imported does report a language - `en-us`. I'm not sure why - maybe the source did activate english at some time.

You should be able to get this going by exporting a content type from the target system and comparing the json with the one you want to import, and probably manually patch it.